# definition of group completion of semirings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, monoid, semiring

I know the group completion of a monoid. If we have a semiring $R$, which is in particular a monoid. Then the group completion of $R$ is an abelian group. But how can we define the completion of a semiring such that the resulting object is a ring?

Comment: [Here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rig#properties) is some discussion about this. Basically, the sensible way to define multiplication works.

Comment: Google "Grothendieck ring" or "ring associated to a semiring". The title does not fit, by the way.